# Can I get this SO query to work for any SE site?

Tags: support, data-explorer

[This query (How much rep would I have if there were no rep cap?)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/824/how-much-rep-would-i-have-if-there-were-no-rep-cap-fixed) only applies to SO, that I can see.  Is there a way I can get it to work on another site, specifically ELU?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execute it on SO, a palette of sites will appear. Click ELU icon and you will be able to run it there.